# What happens to an activity object after onDestroy() gets called?

Tags: android, android-activity

Let's say I have some code of the form

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        myActivity.doStuff();
        myActivity.someField = blabla;
        //etc
    }
},10*1000);
```

and some time during those 10 seconds the activity gets closed and destroyed. What happens to the myActivity object then? Is the reference still valid and can the object's fields and functions still be accessed?

More generally, what happens to the objects created by an activity during its lifecycle? Do they perish with the activity or will there persist as long as there are live references being held to it?

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely that it gets GCed or may be not (depends on available memory).. it may live in the heap but its removed from Activity Stack...

Comment: So it can be GCed even if there are still live references to it being held?